# Typescript object property typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function call like this:

```
var myVar = myFunction({
    property: 'prop',
    functionProperty() {
         console.log(this.property);
    },
    functionProperty2() {
         this.functionProperty();
    }
});
```

Is there any way to add typings to the object you are passing to the function without declaring it first?

And another question, is there a way to make this.functionProperty() know that this refers to the object? Working with VSCode when hovering it doesn't recognize the keyword this as the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the compiler option `noImplicitThis` then `this` will be typed inside your object literal functions correctly.

```
function myFunction<T>(o: T) {

}

var myVar = myFunction({
    property: 'prop',
    functionProperty() {
        console.log(this.property);
    },
    functionProperty2() {
        this.functionProperty();
        this.missing // error

    }
});
```

If you need more control over the type of `this`, you can use `ThisType` which is a special marker for the compiler and will tell the compiler what the type of `this` will be inside the object literal functions (but this will also require `noImplicitAny`).

```
function myFunction<T>(o: T & ThisType<T & { extra: boolean }>) {

}

var myVar = myFunction({
    property: 'prop',
    functionProperty() {
        console.log(this.property);
    },
    functionProperty2() {
        this.functionProperty();
        this.missing // error
        this.extra //ok
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you know any way to declare the property's type?

Comment: What property? Of an object literal? Unless you want to specify the whole type of the object literal, the simplest option is to use a type assertion to the desired type `{ p: null as number} `